# The speed between UI code and UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

There is one project needs to be re-constructed.

Somebody asked me to help do the job.

I noticed 1/3-1/2 of total code are UI code.

My projects are always M-V-C project, UI layer are composed of`UIView`.

Thus I planed to convert the code to `UIView` and try to separate the view & controller.

Just wonder the performance between the 2 mode.

Is there comparation or test of performance difference for `XIB UIView` and `code generated UIView`?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Network on the Developer Tools on every browser. Time of loading of page may be seen there. Anyways, the standard loading of a page is 3-5 seconds.